# Trying to create AWS spot datafeed, getting error: InaccessibleStorageLocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following the 'documentation' here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-data-feeds.html

With the goal of creating an ec2 spot instance price datafeed.

I use this command:

```
aws ec2 create-spot-datafeed-subscription --region us-east-1 --bucket mybucketname-spot-instance-price-data-feed
```

And get this response:

```
An error occurred (InaccessibleStorageLocation) when calling the CreateSpotDatafeedSubscription operation: The specified bucket does not exist or does not have enough permissions
```

The bucket exists, I am able to upload files into it.

I don't have any idea what to do - there's a blizzard of AWS options for giving permissions and the documentation makes only vague statements, nothing concrete about what might need to be done.

Can anyone suggest please what I can do to get past this error?  thanks!

Comment: Does your policy cover this? `You must have FULL_CONTROL permission to the bucket, which includes permission for the s3:GetBucketAcl and s3:PutBucketAcl actions.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked me for this issue is enabling the ACL.  I initially had the ACLs disabled and I was running into the same permissions issue.  I updated the S3 bucket and enabled ACLs then the message went away and I was able to create see the spot pricing feed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although this is a rather vague answer, it did in fact fix the issue. In Bucket permissions, bucket policy was disabled and when I enabled it, it worked. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html